# jsf invalid values on form submission

Tags: jsf

I have a jsf page which contains a selectmanylistbox whose values are an object array provided by a function in my managed. These objects are based on following simple class:

```
public class Category {
private String categoryId;
private String categoryName;
private String[] templates;

public Category(String categoryId, String categoryName) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public Category(String categoryId, String categoryName, String[] templates) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    this.templates = templates;
}

public String getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public String[] getTemplates() {
    return templates;
}

public void setTemplates(String[] templates) {
    this.templates = templates;
}
```

Here is the managed bean function providing the array for selectonelistbox:

```
public Category[] getCategoryValues() {

    categoryValues = new Category[4];

    String[] temp = new String[3];
    temp[0] = "Line 1";
    temp[1] = "Line 2";
    temp[2] = "Line 3";
    categoryValues[0] = new Category("1001", "Category 1", temp);
    temp = new String[3];
    temp[0] = "Line 4";
    temp[1] = "Line 5";
    temp[2] = "Line 6";
    categoryValues[1] = new Category("1002", "Category 2", temp);

    temp = new String[3];
    temp[0] = "Line 7";
    temp[1] = "Line 8";
    temp[2] = "Line 9";

    categoryValues[2] = new Category("1003", "Category 3", temp);

    temp = new String[3];
    temp[0] = "Line 10";
    temp[1] = "Line 11";
    temp[2] = "Line 12";

    categoryValues[3] = new Category("1004", "Category 4", temp);

    return categoryValues;

}
```

Here is the jsf code for this selectmanylistbox:

```
    <h:selectOneListbox value="#{category.selectedCategoryId}"
     onchange="submit()">

        <f:selectItems value="#{category.categoryValues}" var="cat"
            itemLabel="#{cat.categoryName}" itemValue="#{cat.categoryId}" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
```

Additionally, I have used following event to reload the page whenever a category is selected:

```
<f:event listener="#{category.intialize()}" type="preRenderView" />
```

The purpose of reloading the page is to use the selectedcategory as base for a selectmanycheckbox item displaying the array from the selectedcategory as checkboxes. Here is the corresponding jsf code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{category.targetTemplates}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{category.selectedCategoryTemplates}" />
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Where CategoryTemplates is simplay an array of Strings objects.

Now, category selection and page reload works fine and the selectmanycheckbox item is correctly displayed with strings from the selected category as options. When I try to select some check box values and submit them, I got a inavlid values error message and no submission is done. The values used by the selectmanycheckbox are available when the page loads, so what could be the problem?

Here is the initialize() method which is actually doing nothing, I am just using it for the purpose of reloading the page:

```
public void intialize() {

}
```

Here is the html code for the checkboxes:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input name="j_idt4:j_idt8" id="j_idt4:j_idt8:0" value="Line 1" type="checkbox" /><label   
for="j_idt4:j_idt8:0" class=""> Line 1</label></td>
<td>
<input name="j_idt4:j_idt8" id="j_idt4:j_idt8:1" value="Line 2" type="checkbox" /><label   
for="j_idt4:j_idt8:1" class=""> Line 2</label></td>
<td>
<input name="j_idt4:j_idt8" id="j_idt4:j_idt8:2" value="Line 3" type="checkbox" /><label 
for="j_idt4:j_idt8:2" class=""> Line 3</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The actual error message on the console is :

j_idt4:j_idt8: Überprüfungsfehler: Wert ist ungültig.), detail=(j_idt4:j_idt8: Überprüfungsfehler: Wert ist ungültig.)]

Its in German and means that Validation failure, values are invalid

Comment: Please show the error message and the category.intialize() method. Looks like preRenderView is being called again upon your final POST and thus changing the values. The requirement of updating part of the output based on user selection is better handled using ajax...

Comment: I have edited the post, added the html code which is causing errors plus the error message(its in German). I also thought about Ajax but can,t use due to the project requirments

Comment: You are right regarding the initialize() function, it is being called upon submission as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of your managed bean which provides the array for selectonelistbox (method getCategoryValues). It must return the same list in the subsequent request (during submitting the form) as it did during the initial request (before submitting the form, during selecting the value).